# Is it true $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(k \theta) \cos(j \theta) d \theta = 0$ if $j \neq k$ and $j, k \geq 1 $ are integers.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to check if this assertion is true, though i am bit rusty with integration and little unsure how to solve this integral.

Is the following statement true:
$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(k \theta) \cos(j \theta) d \theta = 0$ if $j \neq k$ and $j, k \geq 1$  are integers.

Any pointers of hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes I have some familiarity with them, although no where near as much as i should. I have n't been lucky enough to study complex analysis yet. So have never undertaken complex variable integration. Hopefully one day soon. If you could give me a hint on what approach to use to solve the integral i'll be greatfull.

Comment: In general, the product of two $\sin,\cos$ or a $\sin$ and a $\cos$ may be converted to a sum, using the [product to sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use complex detours, you can use the product formula for $\cos$:

$$\cos a \cos b = \frac12 (\cos(a+b) + \cos(a-b)) $$